# Docker container on raspberry ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, docker, raspberry-pi

I'm new to docker, I didn't find anything that I didn't tried already but I think it is a simple problem.
I'm successfully running a Docker Container on my Raspberry Pi. I can access it locally, but not from my PC ? Why is that ?

On Google Chrome I get this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.
When I run that app on the raspberry directly it works.

Here is my DockerFile :

```js
FROM node:carbon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Here is my simple nodejs code (shouldn't be the problem) :

```js
"use strict"
//require
var express = require('express');
//Conf const
const _port = 3000;

//Server
var app = express();
//Routing
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.send("Hello from my nodejs docker application");
})
.listen(_port, function (){
    console.log('Server listening on : '+_port);
});
```

And here are the command I used to build and run the container :

```
$ docker build -t neito/node-docker-1 .  
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -d neito/node-docker-1
```

(For this i tried several port, and with "-it" options)

So.. Someone can see the problem ?

Have a nice day everyone,

Neito

Comment: Have you tried seeing the logs? ```docker logs  neito/node-docker-1 ```

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` implies that you cannot reach the port 3000 of your raspberry pi from your pc. I have the suspicion this is unrelated to docker, and more an issue with your port settings of your raspberry pi. Can you ssh your raspberry pi successfully from your PC?